Drawing rectangle of road line with width as minimum distance between two buildings in QGIS
I have two layers:

line vector layer representing the road
polygon vector layer representing the buildings

How can I derive a rectangle shape (refer to green rectangle) for each road line whereby the width of the rectangle is the minimum distance between 2 buildings on both sides of the road?
The method cannot be manual drawing/measurement as there are many features to work on.


Is there any option to cluster/dissolve your buildings using a common ID? Are there any ranges, how wide/narrow your roads can be?

It isn't clear, rectangle's width should be the distance of nearest polygon to road (linestring) in both sides? And what about the criteria for rectangle's length, it would be linestring's vertices or nearest polygon vertices? in your example looks arbitrary.

@Erik  There is no attribute to cluster buildings. :( This is what I am trying to find out - the narrowest of the roads. any ideas?

@PepeNO
yes, rectangle's width is the distance of nearest polygon to  road (linestring) on both sides. Rectangle's length can be obtained from attribute "length_in_metre" of the linestring. Each green rectangle is corresponding to a linestring. Hope this clarifies.
Can you advise how on to get rectangle's width? Thanks!

Please add such relevant information to your question directly when posting it.

Assuming your lines actually are the center of the road, you first run join attributes by nearest, using the lines as the first input, and the polygons as the second. Make sure you only join the one closest feature to each line. This will add a field named "distance" to your lines, which contains the distance you want to know.
Then buffer your joined lines by that distance value, using a flat end style.

"join attributes by nearest" only gives me distance of 1 closest feature on 1 side of the road. I need distance of 1 closest feature on both sides of the road and sum them up. How to do that?

This is the second time you state some information which should have been clearly in the question to begin with.

The green boxes drawn do illustrate that though this is not stated explicitly in text. Apology. Appreciate your assistance on this request. Thanks.
